# How to call print function if I changed the original view class?

Tags: mfc

I'm an MFC user.
In my code, there are two Views with split bar which are filled with buttons on the left and signals on the right side.
And, I tried to call the print functions which include print preview,    **OnPreparePrinting()**,**OnPaint()** what so ever, through a button which is made by me and called *PrintScreen* on the menu, but it didn't work.

How can I connect from the menu button with the print functions?

And how can I project the both images from the two views on one page?

P.S. I've googled a lot, but I couldn't find completely the same as my situation. If someone knows this solution or information, please link or leave any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFC only supports printing for one view only, as long as you don't write your own print routines.

When you have two views divided by a splitter, one should be the active one. (Usually the view with the focus). In this case all standard commands like printing route to the one view that is active.

When you want that both views including the splitter to be printed, you have to write your own code. A simple solution would be calling the print functions for both views one after another.